# Wildfly 8 CPU, Memory issue

Tags: java, wildfly-8

While perform a load testing on a application in Wildfly-8.0, both memory and cpu are hiked up. After stopped the testing both memory and cpu went down to 50% but the server fails to accept any request even from the server hosted machine facing the same problem with wildfly console

No clue has been found when we monitor the object created in server through Visual VM, so is this issue with wildfly-8.0 version since we wonder why the application server doesn't accept any request even after the resource consumption went below 50%.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the log files.  Look for any unexplained exceptions.  (OOME's in particular can lead to lockups.)

Next, use jstack or similar to get a dump of the thread stacks.  Check that the listener thread is still alive and that there idle worker threads ready to process requests.

There are a variety of things that can cause lockups under heavy load.  Common syndromes include:

- OOMEs causing threads to die, leaving data structures locked, or other threads waiting for `notify` events or similar that are never going to arrive.
- Synchronization or similar problems triggered by the load.